# DataNucleus getObjectById returns null for forighn key objetcs

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdo, datanucleus

I have following persistable class

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class PasswordRecovery {

@PrimaryKey @Expose
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.UNSPECIFIED)
private String id;

@Persistent @Expose
private long time;

@Persistent @Expose
private User user;


public PasswordRecovery(String id, long time, User user) {
    this.id = id;
    this.time = time;
    this.user = user;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(long time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

Now I am using following code to get the above object filled with DB values,

```
PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
    //PasswordRecovery retObj = null;// = new PasswordRecovery();
    try {           
        PasswordRecovery record = pm.getObjectById(PasswordRecovery.class, id);

        if (null == record) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You are not authorized for this");
        }
        else {                               
            return record;
        }

    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
```

Now when I call,`record.getUser()`, it returns null. Is there any configuration which needs to be done. Following is code for how I create the PersistenceManagerFactory.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
                   properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass","org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory");
            properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL","jdbc:mysql://localhost/db");                        properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName","username");
properties.setProperty("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword","password");
properties.setProperty("datanucleus.autoCreateSchema","true");
properties.setProperty("datanucleus.autoCreateSchema","true");
properties.setProperty("datanucleus.autoCreateSchema","true");
properties.setProperty("datanucleus.autoCreateTables","true");
pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(properties);
```

I am pretty new to DataNucleus JDO? Is there anything missing in configuration?

Comment: what is this trying to achieve ? @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.UNSPECIFIED). You have an unspecified value strategy?! what does that mean? Why do you have @Persistent on every field?

Comment: I am pretty new to data-nucleus. I want to store randomly generated string as it is into the primary key hence I specified @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.UNSPECIFIED). Other than this, my all values are getting stored into DB so I have specified @Persistent on every field.

Comment: Unless you tell it how these "randomly generated strings" are generated then it won't generate ANYTHING (and persist what value you put in there). You don't need @Persistent on every field, they get persisted by default!

Comment: Randomly generated string are getting generated using "UUID.randomUUID().toString()" java code. I will remove @Persistent from other fields.

Comment: Still getUser returns null. Please suggest if anybody faced same error.

Answer (score 1):

So presuming the object is returned by getObjectById then you should look at JDO object lifecycle states, and understand that once an object is outside the transaction it is HOLLOW, hence all relation fields lose their values unless you set datanucleus.retainValues